# onDomReady like event in react.js

Tags: reactjs

I'm using react.js to render my page.

Is there a way to detect the moment when the page was loaded?

Maybe something similar to onDomReady event.

Comment: @perror, how is your link related to react.js ??

Comment: My fault... ignore the comment. I'll destroy it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`React.render` takes a callback that is executed when the component is rendered: <sup>[docs](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.render)</sup>

> ```javascript
> ReactComponent render(
>   ReactElement component,
>   DOMElement container,
>   [function callback]
> )
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> If the optional callback is provided, it will be executed after the component is rendered or updated.

You could watch for the execution of this function to determine when your component is rendered.

Comment: How do I listen to children component changes? Or is this callback fired whenever there is a change anywhere inside that component?

Comment: each component fires its own